# Google Appengine and rx-Java?

Tags: google-app-engine, rx-java

Is rxJava library compatible with Google Appengine?  If so are there any limitations?  The only info I have found is mention of 'partial support' on grepcode.  http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.netflix.rxjava/rxjava-core/0.9.0

What is not supported?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the limitation of Java Threads in Google Appengine: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/#Java_The_sandbox

RxJava uses Java `Thread` and `Executor` in the `Scheduler` implementations. So the codes which get involved some concurrent `Scheduler`s can not run in Google Java Sandbox.

If you want to use `Scheduler` in Google Appengine, you need to implement a special `Scheduler` by yourself. Besides, some operators may use `Scheduler` by default, such as `delay` use `Schedulers.computation()` by default. Remember to use their `Scheduler` overload methods.

Answer (score 6):

You should create a child of RxJavaSchedulersHook and override its methods using your scheduler which use `com.google.appengine.api.ThreadManager`:
I've done it like this :

```
public class MyThreadSchedulersHook extends RxJavaSchedulersHook {

private final Executor executor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(10, ThreadManager.backgroundThreadFactory());

@Override
public Scheduler getComputationScheduler() {
    return Schedulers.from(executor);
}

@Override
public Scheduler getIOScheduler() {
    return Schedulers.from(executor);
}

@Override
public Scheduler getNewThreadScheduler() {
    return Schedulers.from(executor);
}
}
```

Then you should register this hook. Better to do this in an ServletContextListener implementation:

```
public class ContextListener implements ServletContextListener {

@Override
public void contextInitialized(final ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
    RxJavaPlugins.getInstance().registerSchedulersHook(new RxMainThreadSchedulersHook());
}

@Override
public void contextDestroyed(final ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
    // App Engine does not currently invoke this method.
}
}
```

It works for me.

Comment: Does this still work for you? I am still getting the Permission denied security exception.

My hook does get registered before the security exception. I am assuming `MyThreadSchedulersHook` and `RxMainThreadSchedulersHook` are the same class that you just renamed in between updating this post.

Comment: Yes, you are right, RxMainThreadSchedulersHook and MyThreadSchedulersHook are the same classes. And it still works for me. There is the github thread, where I described my problem and then found the decision -  https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/2918 

It's important to call Schedulers.from(executor) in the methods of the hook, and don't define Schedulers class before the hook registration.

Comment: Interesting.  This doesn't work on front-end modules, right?

Comment: @user1923898 found my issue - it was with Retrofit, which automatically spawns a new thread for its RxJava implementation. Need to find a way to override that thread creation.

Comment: @Patrick ThreadManager.currentRequestThreadFactory() is what you want...

Comment: nowadays `RxJavaPlugins.getInstance()` is **deprecated** and you should use _RxJavaSchedulersHook_ / _RxJavaHooks_ e.g. `RxJavaSchedulersHook.createNewThreadScheduler(ThreadManager.currentRequestThreadFactory())` which will return an `Scheduler` that you would pass to `RxJavaHooks. onNewThreadScheduler(Scheduler)`