# Problems threads with RxJava and AppEngine

Tags: google-app-engine, rx-java

App Engine use their on way to create/handle treads and in order to use RxScheduler you need to implement your own hook like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23701504/google-appengine-and-rx-java)

My problems still persist with RxRingBuffer using rx-java 1.1.6

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "modifyThreadGroup")
  at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:472)
  at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:884)
  at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$CustomSecurityManager.checkPermission(DevAppServerFactory.java:445)
  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory$CustomSecurityManager.checkAccess(DevAppServerFactory.java:470)
  at java.lang.ThreadGroup.checkAccess(ThreadGroup.java:315)
  at java.lang.Thread.init(Thread.java:391)
  at java.lang.Thread.init(Thread.java:349)
  at java.lang.Thread.<init>(Thread.java:548)
  at rx.internal.util.RxThreadFactory.newThread(RxThreadFactory.java:39)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.<init>(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:612)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:925)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.ensurePrestart(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1587)
  at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.delayedExecute(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:334)
  at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
  at rx.internal.util.ObjectPool.start(ObjectPool.java:112)
  at rx.internal.util.ObjectPool.<init>(ObjectPool.java:59)
  at rx.internal.util.ObjectPool.<init>(ObjectPool.java:36)
  at rx.internal.util.RxRingBuffer$1.<init>(RxRingBuffer.java:280)
  at rx.internal.util.RxRingBuffer.<clinit>(RxRingBuffer.java:280)
  at rx.internal.operators.OperatorPublish$PublishSubscriber.<init>(OperatorPublish.java:248)
  at rx.internal.operators.OperatorPublish$1.call(OperatorPublish.java:60)
  at rx.internal.operators.OperatorPublish$1.call(OperatorPublish.java:49)
  at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:50)
  at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
  at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:50)
  at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeLift.call(OnSubscribeLift.java:30)
  at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:8759)
  at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:8726)
  at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:8549)
```

Comment: could be related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25365848/access-denied-java-lang-runtimepermission-modifythreadgroup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some investigation i found the problem it is rx-java version 1.1.X, we can use rx-java 1.0.X in GAE with the hook solution detailed in the question

So i [open an issue in rx-java](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/4171)

**Update**

after rx-java 1.1.7 it's posible to use last version of rx with GAE, just need to use new RxJavaHook inside a ContextListener instead of RxJavaPlugin.getInstance().registerSchedulerHook()

```
public class RxServletContextListener implements ServletContextListener {

private static final ScheduledExecutorService THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(10, ThreadManager.currentRequestThreadFactory());

@Override
public void contextInitialized(final ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
    Scheduler gaeScheduler = Schedulers.from(THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
    RxJavaHooks.onIOScheduler(gaeScheduler);
    RxJavaHooks.onComputationScheduler(gaeScheduler);
    RxJavaHooks.onNewThreadScheduler(gaeScheduler);
    RxJavaHooks.setOnGenericScheduledExecutorService(new Func0<ScheduledExecutorService>() {
        @Override
        public ScheduledExecutorService call() {
            return THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR;
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void contextDestroyed(final ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
    // App Engine does not currently invoke this method.
}
```

}

Comment: Was unable to get this working.  I'm using basic-scaling and the code above and still getting the java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "modifyThreadGroup").  Also working with Retrofit 1.9

Comment: i don't think relevant `basic-scaling`, have you debug your code in local and checked it's pass through contextInitialized method? which version of rx-java are you using?

Comment: Found the issue.  Retrofit creates its own threads.   Worked fine after switching to synchronous retrofit calls.

Comment: Patrick you could modify your Retrofit thread in RestAdapter.setExecutors https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/parent-1.9.0/retrofit/src/main/java/retrofit/RestAdapter.java#L607